# executing Linux sed command and version control complain

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a folder which contains jsp files. I used *find* and *sed* to change part of the text in some files. This folder is under version control. The command successfully changed all the occurrences of the specified pattern **But**

The problem is when I'm synchronizing the folder with the remote repository I can see so many files listed as modified which actually nothing in that file has changed. There is sth wrong with the white space I suppose. Could anyone shed  some light on this matter.

I'm trying to replace `../../images/spacer` to `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/spacer` in all jsp files under current folder
The command I'm using is as below

```
 find . -name '*.jsp' -exec sed -i 's/..\/..\/images\/spacer/${pageContext.request.contextPath}\/static\/images\/spacer/g' {} \;
```

Comment: using the `-i` option is forcing the re-write of all files. You need to add a filter to retrieve only the files that need to be edited, so `find ... | grep -l 'srchTarg' | xargs sed -i '....' {}` might help. Try only on test data! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, I managed to narrow the result down then appllied the sed command but I can still see the issue. Now, it is limited to just files containing the search pattern. When I compare the files I can see some lines being highlighted as modified without any actual modification. So to summarize the issue is still there but limited to the files containing the search pattern

Comment: so you need another filter that removes the files that contain the fixed search pattern. maybe `find ... | grep -l 'srchTarg' | xargs grep -vl 'fixedPattern' {} | xargs sed -i '...' {}` ? (Work on test files!). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In most of systems, grep has an option to recursively search for files that contains a pattern, avoiding `find`.

So, the command would be:

```
grep -r -l -m1 "\.\./\.\./images/spacer" --include \*.jsp | 
    xargs -r sed -i 's!\.\./\.\./\(images/spacer\)!${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/\1!g'
```

**Explanation**

Both `grep` and `sed` work with regular expression patterns, in which th dot character `.` represent any character including the dot itself. In order to explicit indicate a dot, it must be escaped with a `\` before it. So to search `..` is necessary specify `\.\.`, or it can match texts like `ab/cd/`

Now, about the grep options:

- `-m1` stops search when finds the first occurrence avoiding search the entire file.
- `-r` search recursively in the directories
- `--include \*.jsp` search only in files with FILEPAT file pattern.